# The system is running in low graphics mode, cannot open GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a HP pavilion Laptop. I am getting this error and unable to get into desktop.

I have tried this "[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)" method but no matter what I do I cannot open GRUB menu neither can I fix this issue.

I believe I took the wrong decision to shift from Windows to Ubuntu just for being open source. I completely formatted OEM Windows 8 and now I am left with dead laptop.

NOTE: I cannot log into any menu so I can enter any commands, all I see is tty1 menu (Black screen command prompt style)

Comment: To access GRUB: "Hold down (right) SHIFT to display the menu during boot. **In certain cases, pressing the ESC key may also display the menu.**" if this won't work perhaps [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) helps. Did you try to disable some UEFI Settings https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI ?

Comment: You probably do not need to go into grub to fix your low graphics error. What video card do you have? Can you post the output of `xrandr`. If you have Nvidia graphics, did you install the proprietary drivers?

Comment: Thanks to all, upon some research running this command "sudo apt-get install fglrx" in the prompt window that I mentioned above fixed the issue.