# How to access GRUB menu?

Tags: updates, gnome-terminal, grub-efi

**On Mac with a live-usb (Ubuntu 16.04.4).**

Is it by pressing `shift` during the boot? 
If so, when exactly? Being on a live usb doesn’t help with “timing”.
Also, should i press it until the GRUB menu shows up or only click?

Comment: Found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/471005/the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-cannot-open-grub#comment623401_471005 BUT IT’S NOT VERY CLEAR, when should i press `shift`?

Comment: Do not know if different with Mac, but hold shift is with BIOS/CSM/Legacy boot not UEFI. With UEFI boot it is escape but press perhaps several times to catch correct timing on a PC.  And if a MAC you should be using UEFI. EFI-Booting Ubuntu on a Mac
http://www.rodsbooks.com/ubuntu-efi/

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac using live-usb with EFI the key to access the GRUB menu is <kbd>esc</kbd>.

Comment: I did not put a follow-up question. I already asked a new one.

Comment: I meant the part of your answer that [I removed](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1014633/revisions).

Comment: I meant the exact same thing. I didn’t made any question. There are no questions in the part that you removed... Maybe i should ask you for the definition of “question” if it has a different meaning inside here. I posted the solution to the answer, a list (2) of my other problems that i’m facing and then thanked for the support gave to me.

Comment: Well, I meant the new problem you mentioned. This is a Q&A site and problem is much like a synonym to question here.

Comment: **So I can’t mention new/other problems in answers?** As they can be misunderstood as a ”synonym to question”? What if i need to do so to actually have an answer to the original question? I understood what you are saying, we’re just playing with words at this point, i just don’t think that the part you removed has to be removed because technically it doesn’t violate any “term of use”. I don’t think that moderators should be allowed to remove parts because of their thoughts or just because they don’t like something. If a thing is not denied, i can do that.

Comment: You should not mention things that are not related to the solution of the original question. Keep in mind this is a knowledge base much more than a forum. (Forum-like contents are acceptable in comments only.) Your answer to your own question should look just like anyone other’s answer to it. Would you consider an answer to be good if the answerer introduced their own problems in it? I don’t think so. You can also refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/283579/217657.

Comment: So the problem as i already said, It’s not about follow-up questions, is about staying strictly on the subject. I signed up 1 week ago. You were a perfect user back then? I don’t think so. You should be more precise about the reason and pay more attention if you want to remove anything. If you gave me the correct motivation in the first place we would have finished by the **first** comment. Thanks for the clarification, now that i know it i will make 1 question for each problem that i’m facing :)

Answer (score 1):

On the "Silent PC" brand machine I'm using I need to use F1 key during boot to access the grub menu.

Pressing the escape key will also stop the boot process, but it drops me in to the grub command-line-interface, rather than the menu.

Shift during boot doesn't seem to do anything at all on this machine.